# SELECT where Weekday = Monday, Tuesday etc

Tags: ms-access

How can I `SELECT` rows that are from a certain day of the week? I am aware of `Weekday(#01/01/2014#)` which returns the correct number representing the day, but am unsure of how to use this as part of the `WHERE` clause.

I have tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM problems
WHERE problems.start_date = Weekday(5);
```

To try and get all rows that fall on a Thursday but have had no success.

And

```
SELECT *
FROM problems
WHERE problems.start_date = WeekdayName(1,True);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I say

```
SELECT tbl.Updated, Weekday([updated]) AS WDay
FROM tbl
WHERE Weekday([updated])=3
```

(Given that the field updated is a date data type)

I will get Tuesday, because the week begins on Sunday in my locale, however, I can specify a start day ( http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/weekday.php ) if that is not suitable.